# Centrar controles dentro de un form maximizado

Tags: c#, .net

Quisiera poner `cinco controles picturebo`x alineados justo en el medio superior de la pantalla. (La longitud de la pantalla es diferente por cada usuario).

Para empezar mi idea es que la ventana esté `maximizada`, para obtener el tamaño total del `form`. (El `form` será `transparente`, con su propiedad `backcolor`), de ahi que necesite ubicar las `5 imagenes` justo en el `medio superior` de la pantalla.

Mi idea era, que una vez obtuviese la medida en `pixeles totales`, lo dividiese en dos, y retase la mitad de la longitud del primer control.

Tal que, si la `longitud` es `1000`, y la `imagen` es de `50x50`, tendría que ponerlo a partir de `1000/2 -25 = 475`.

La imagen estaría situada entre el pixel `475` y el `525`. Perfectamente alineada.

Este es el código:

```
int tamañoimg = Invocador1.Size.Height; 
int centro = this.Height / 2 - ( tamañoimg / 2 );
Invocador1.Left = centro;
```

Pero la posición no es exactamente la mitad, sino aproximadamene 1/4 hacia la derecha.

Leyendo, he oido que podría deberse a que cuándo se carga el formulario éste aún no obtiene el numero de pixeles reales al máximizar la ventana.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas usando medidas de altura, para luego poder situarlas de forma horizontal...

Deberías usar la propiedad `Width` que mide el ancho.

```
int tamañoimg = Invocador1.Size.Width; 
int centro = this.Width/ 2 - ( tamañoimg / 2 );
Invocador1.Left = centro;
```

Comment: Me siento estupido, no me estaba dando cuenta de que lo que estaba midiendo era la altura de la ventana y no el ancho... Muchas gracias! :)

Answer (score 2):

¿Has intentado con algún control?, como el TableLayoutPanel y de ahí basarte en agregar los picturebox que necesites.

Saludos.

Comment: Exacto, para eso están los distintos paneles.

Answer (score 0):

'CENTRA AUTOMATICAMENTE EL CONTROL EN EL FORMULARIO EN CUALQUIER TAMAÑO DEL FORMULARIO

```
    PictureBox1.Left = (Me.ClientSize.Width - PictureBox1.Width) / 2
    PictureBox1.Top = (Me.ClientSize.Height - PictureBox1.Height) / 2
```